# Visual Studio 2015 hangs when adding/deleting project resources

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to do a simple thing:

- Right click on Windows Forms project
- Click properties
- Navigate to 'Resources' tab
- Attempt to add new png or delete existing png
- Visual Studio hangs

If I add a png to the windows explorer folder for resources, it won't show up in my project resources. Problem also occurs with jpegs (and I assume any type of resource I would try to add).

This appears to be a problem with this particular solution. If I create a new solution and add a new png resource, it works just fine, and I'm able to use the resource in my project.

Comment: Try to add JPG instated  of JPEG

Answer (score 1):

First try to clean your solution by recreate solution and recreate the build solution. If this doesn't work restart pc (you might have done this) but finally i think a possible way to solve this, is to reset your Visual Studio user cache:

[If you have problems with TFS or Visual Studio flush the user cache … or not?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willy-peter_schaub/archive/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not.aspx)

1. Delete the contents from the following folders

   - C:\Users\<>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation
   - C:\Users\<>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio
   - C:\Users\<>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VSCommon
2. Go to the Visual Studio IDE folder in command prompt and Run the following command "devenv /resetuserdata" from the Visual Studio IDE folder.

   - Typical location for 32 bit: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE
   - Typical location for 64 bit: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Unfortunately, the problem still occurs after trying all of those things. Again, I think this is a problem with just this solution, as other solutions I have have don't have this problem.